# PHP script INSERTs INTO database twice when code is executed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a very simple PHP insert into script and it doubles the entries every time it's executed.

(To be sure I'm not executing the script twice I used the mail() function to email me when it is executed and I only get one email)

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$pass = "password";
$muser    = "username";
$dbconn = mysql_connect($hostname, $muser, $pass);
$db ="database";
mysql_select_db($db);
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES ('happy', 'birthday')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Is there more code surrounding this?  Maybe this entire block is being run twice?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three ways this could happen:

1. The code you posted is contained in a function that gets called twice.
2. Your page is reloaded, executing the call twice.
3. Another process (cron job, backup utility) is duplicating the data.

Since you said you get only one email, we can probably rule out #2 (unless your email server has a rate limiter, and only sends one of the two messages).

We can rule out #1 for the same reason, unless the mail() call is not contained in the same function as the mysql_query() call.

So we are left with looking for another process that is duplicating the data. The code you posted is not sufficient to make this determination.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a longshot, but if you are calling the script from the browser and on the page generated by the script you have a `<img>` tag with empty `src` attribute then the browser will assume for this image same url as url of your script and will call your script additional time.

I think same goes for any other html tag that loads external resource.

The fact that you get only one email speaks against such scenario but I'd checked it out anyway if I were you.